# Binary Tree Deletion

Tags: c, tree

Given: The deleteTree() function deletes the tree, but doesn’t change root to NULL which may cause problems if the user of deleteTree() doesn’t change root to NULL and tries to access values using root pointer. We can modify the deleteTree() function to take reference to the root node so that this problem doesn’t occur.

[a link]http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-to-delete-a-tree/

Doubt: In the deleteTree function the copy of the node from the main is passed then how are the actual memory of all these nodes freed in the deleteTree(). It is said the tree is deleted but for the tree to be deleted shouldn't we pass the address. Also if we consider that the tree is actually deleted then along with it the root node is also deleted so why doesn't it change to NULL in the main?

```
void deleteTree(struct node* node) 
{
  if (node == NULL) return;
  deleteTree(node->left);
  deleteTree(node->right);
  printf("\n Deleting node: %d", node->data);
  free(node);
}
int main()
{
  struct node *root = newNode(1); 
  root->left            = newNode(2);
  root->right          = newNode(3);
  root->left->left     = newNode(4);
  root->left->right   = newNode(5); 

  deleteTree(root);  
  root = NULL;

  printf("\n Tree deleted ");

  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

The modified code:

```
void _deleteTree(struct node* node)
{
  if (node == NULL) return;

  _deleteTree(node->left);
  _deleteTree(node->right);
  printf("\n Deleting node: %d", node->data);
  free(node);
}


void deleteTree(struct node** node_ref)
{
  _deleteTree(*node_ref);
  *node_ref = NULL;
}

int main()
{
  struct node *root = newNode(1);
  root->left            = newNode(2);
  root->right          = newNode(3);
  root->left->left     = newNode(4);
  root->left->right   = newNode(5);


  deleteTree(&root);
  printf("\n Tree deleted ");

  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

How does the freeing happen in this case what if we set the root=NULL in main and not in the deleteTree function?

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh In the 1st code, only the node pointer is passed and not the address of it, if we want the changes to be reflected outside the deleteTree function we should pass the address that is what I know.

Comment: Sorry i mis-read your code. Removed the comments.

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh But why can't we set root to NULL in the first case while we can do so in the second case?

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing two concepts - memory freeing, and setting the pointer to `NULL`. By using `free` the memory is freed and th pointer now points to an unallocated piece of memory. By setting the node* to NULL, you are indicating that the pointer is not valid - you can see that the code checks for that - `if (node ==`NULL`) return;`. If you just set the root to NULL you are creating a memory leak, since the memory pointed to remains allocated.

Also - `It is said the tree is deleted but for the tree to be deleted shouldn't we pass the address` - you are passing the address - `deleteTree(&root);` - root is a node* containing the address of the root node.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes we are passing the address in the second case but what about the first case we are not passing the address there, we are passing the root.

Comment: in the first case you pass `root` which is a `node*` type - an address.

Comment: node* basically states root is a struct node type pointer, is it an address? Aren't we passing just the pointer in the 1st case?

Comment: a pointer is a variable containing an address - http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/

Comment: yes so by passing pointers we can actually delete the nodes but why can't we set the root node to null in the main? In the delete function we delete all the nodes including the root node and after that we are setting the root to null so that there is no memory leak but here it is saying that root=null in the main actually doesn't happen?

Answer (score 0):

In the first code, function `void deleteTree(struct node* node)` calls itself(recursion) to free the memory of each node.`It is said the tree is deleted but for the tree to be deleted shouldn't we pass the address`, in fact the para `node` is a address of one node, it is a pointer(`struct node *`). When you call `free(node)`, you free the memory which the `node` points to, not the node itself.

As for set root to `NULL`, the second code is same with your first code logically. If the function `void deleteTree(struct node** node_ref)` is inline, then after compiling, it will be same with your first code.

Comment: what i was asking is for the 1st case why can't we set the root to null in the main, the tree is deleted fine but after deleting it we are setting the root to null so that it doesn't point to any unallocated place of memory but here it is said that the root doesn't change too null, why is it so?